# anaconda not working anymore

Tags: anaconda

When I run the command `which python`, I get 
`/home/user/anaconda2/bin/python`

but after running  python it shows

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
```

P.S- I had anaconda installed and had been using it for a long time, but recently I tried to switch to python3 by using alias command. Since then I am not able to get back to anaconda, even editing the `~/.bashrc` file does not get me back to anaconda.

Comment: `which python`depends on established $PATH variable. It's better to type `command -v python` to know where it's installed.

Comment: It shows that python is installed in the usr/lib/python2.7 directory. However, how do I get set anaconda as my default python? I have many libraries installed in anaconda, but I'm not able to use them as it is not default anymore.

Comment: I think `update -alternatives` may do it. Type `update-alternatives --display python` and tell me the result.